# This method implicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons

Tags: .net, configuration, .net-4.0, nant

I have just updated my nant script to compile my .net framework 4 solution.
And I got the above error while generating commonassemblyinfo.cs in my solution.
I visited msdn website and also added

`<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />`

in my web.config under runtime->configuration.
But that didn't solve my problem.

Can anyone please suggest what am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET 4.0 AppDomain: obsoleted Evidence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698711/net-4-0-appdomain-obsoleted-evidence)

Comment: I actually saw the question, but didn't help me in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the [latest NAnt build](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nant/files/nant/0.91-alpha1/)? The 0.91 release is in alpha, and supports building .NET 4 applications.

I had tried just updating the NAnt 0.86 configuration to support .NET 4, but got the error you showed. I downloaded the most recent NAnt build, and it worked. Despite being alpha, it seems stable, so far anyway.

There is an [open request](http://sourceforge.net/apps/wordpress/nant/2010/05/24/a-call-to-arms/) for folks to test the new build and report bugs.

Comment: Yeah I using old nant, I think I may need to upgrade my nant to use .net 4.